# Oracle apex change default columns preferences/ settings

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

When creating a table, Apex sets many default settings for each column.
I wonder if some of those default settings can be changed.

Especially I'm talking about the "Enable Users To" section. which is marked "yes" for all, and it is very time-consuming to make them "no" for each column.
Another setting I would like to set is the naming for the column which is currently "Proper case/ Title case" (The first letter on each word is capitalized), but we want only the first word to be capitalized.

Thanks.

example:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of "Enable users to" issue:

- in "Rendering", select all columns whose properties you'd want to change

  - how? Hold the `CTRL` key and left-click columns
- on the right hand side - within columns' "Properties" sections, only **common** properties will be displayed. One of those will be "Enable users to"
- now enable (or disable) any property you want - it'll affect all selected columns

---

As of *capitalized first letter* issue, no idea, sorry.

Comment: WOW, I didn't know multiple columns can be selected, You changed my world thanks!